# Disable controls of MDI form when child is open

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I have an MDIParent Form named MainForm. It has a child form named SelectDB. In the SelectDB form I have a button which when clicked opens FileDialog to browse and select a .MDB file. The path of the file is displayed in a TextBox. After I get the .MDB file the Child form closes and the MainForm is visible. On the MainForm I have a Label which should display the path I got in Textbox. And moreover, when the Child Form is open. The Menu Strip should also be disable, or you can say all the controls in the MDI Form should be disabled.

[image]

My MainForm.vb (MDIParent) code is like this:

Imports System.Windows.Forms

```
Public Class MainForm

    Private Sub MainForm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        sDB.MdiParent = Me
        sDB.Show()
    End Sub

    Public Sub Formload()
        msMenu.Enabled = True
        lblPath.Text = OG.GetValue("DBPath")
        Me.Refresh()
    End Sub
End Class
```

My SelectDB.vb (Child form) code is like this:

```
Public Class SelectDB    

    Private Sub btnBrowse_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnBrowse.Click
        Dim dlg As New OpenFileDialog
        dlg.DefaultExt = ".txt"
        dlg.Filter = "MDB Files (*.mdb)|*.mdb"
        Dim result As Nullable(Of Boolean) = dlg.ShowDialog()
        If result = True Then
            Dim filename As String = dlg.FileName
            txtPath.Text = filename
        End If
        OG.SetValue("DBPath", txtPath.Text)
        main.Formload()
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Application.Exit()
    End Sub

    Private Sub SelectDB_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        Application.Exit()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: This should be a dialog displayed with ShowDialog(), not an MDI child.  You'll get everything else you asked about for free.

Comment: Yeah, use `ShowDialog()` instead of `Show()` and the child view will gain focus and the parent view will block focus until the child is closed.

Comment: What if I want to show the child form inside the MDI Form. Using ShowDialog() only shows the Child form.\

Comment: ShowDialog() will just show your "childform" and then disable your MDIForm. Or if you want your MDIForm to be the container of your childform, just type ShowDialog(Me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place `me.dispose()` in place of `me.hide()` . This will help you to do the intended work.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options for what you're trying to achieve and (what Hans Passant already mentions) is the most easy one: use ShowDialog() not Show.

**Second option:** first of all you *could* create a public method in the main form and call that method from the client on opening and closing. Like:

[main form]

```
public void ChildControls(bool IsEnabled)
{
  msMenu.Enabled = IsEnabled;
}
```

[child]

```
 private void child_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.MdiParent != null)
            ((mainForm)this.MdiParent).ChildControls(false);
    }
    private void child_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.MdiParent != null)
            ((mainForm)this.MdiParent).ChildControls(true);
    }
```

**Third option**:

Use the mainform' MdiChildActivate event. When the `ActiveMdiChild == null` you could enable the controls again. But when you're using MdiChildActivate and you have more (and different) Mdi (child-) forms you should perform a type-check before (de-) activating the controls.